# How to show zoomed out web browser in vb6.0

Tags: vb6

This is the code am using for zoomed out web browser

```
Const OLECMDID_OPTICAL_ZOOM = 63
Const OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER = 2

Web1.ExecWB OLECMDID_OPTICAL_ZOOM, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER, CLng(35), vbNull
```

when i use the code i get the following runtime error:

> -2147221248 (80040100): Automation Error

Any ideas?

Edited:
I use the code given by you. It works fine in debug mode once i take exe and run it shows the following error.[image]

Comment: Works for me win7x64/IE9 but I can reproduce if I attempt the change when there is no loaded document; are you ensuring you only change the zoom after a document has loaded?

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your reply. I am using a Microsoft web browser control to show an internet page on a form.How do i scale the page down to see it 35% smaller?

Comment: Are you ensuring you only change the zoom after a document has loaded?

Comment: Alex, the Percentage of scaling the document happens at run time depends on the web browser size. i hard code the percentage of value (35%)smaller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This only works once a document has loaded, then seems to persist for subsequent navigation.

If you attempt to change the optical zoom when there is no DOM document, error 80040100 occurs.

The code below simply sets zoom initially at the appropriate time;

```
Private Const OLECMDID_OPTICAL_ZOOM As Long = 63
Private Const OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER As Long = 2

Private mblHasSetZoom As Boolean

Private Sub Form_Load()
    web1.Navigate2 "http://www.google.com"
End Sub

Private Sub web1_DocumentComplete(ByVal pDisp As Object, URL As Variant)
If Not mblHasSetZoom Then
    web1.ExecWB OLECMDID_OPTICAL_ZOOM, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER, 35&
    mblHasSetZoom = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Alex, i just run the above code i got run time-error -2147221248 (80040100): Automation Error.The error message is method ExecWB of object "IWebBrowser2" failed

Comment: I'm not sure then, the only way I could get that error was when there was no doc, the example above works for me. What version if IE are you using?

Comment: Hi Alex, am sorry the above code works in windows 95 but not works in windows 7 ultimate it shows the -2147221248 (80040100): Automation Error

Comment: I get the error as well even on first loading of the browser control. I just put in a kludge : On Error Resume Next and it works fine.